# Request too long Error 400. Remove the process that goes to Account/Login.aspx

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, master-pages

I was wondering on you block the website from going to the Account/login.aspx page? I can not seem to find it anywhere. We are getting a Bad Request - Request Too Long HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long message.

The URL for example:  12.34.45.789/Account/Login?ReturnURL=%2FAccount.... and it goes on and on. Lol.

I tried this...

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
   <requestLimits maxQueryString="50000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

in the web.config file and various others like this.  So I figure if I remove the link that goes to Account/login.aspx then this will no longer appear.

We have Visual Studio 2013. Running IIS 10.

Comment: Try changing `maxQueryString` like this: `<requestLimits maxQueryString="4096" />`

Comment: Tried that. That does not work as well.